# How to get all textual elements on my current viewport using JS

Tags: javascript

I have a JS function that gathers all the `<p>` elements on my current viewport. I want to modify this function to get all the textual elements on my current viewport. I know I can use `document.querySelectorAll('p, h1, h2...')` but I wanted to ask if there is any other way to get all the textual elements so that I can make it generic(Like some pages might have textual elements which are different from textual elements from some other page). Also I have created this function keeping in mind that I'll be testing this on browser console as I won't be having access to the frontend code of the websites I'll be testing the code on. Thank you in advance!

Here is my JS Function code:-

```
 async function getVisibleParagraphs() {
      console.log('This works too')
      const paragraphs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('p'))
      let visibleParagraphs = ''

      for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
        const paragraph = paragraphs[i]
        const rect = paragraph.getBoundingClientRect()

        if (rect.bottom >= 0 && rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)||rect.top >= 0 && rect.top <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
          // visibleParagraphs.push(paragraph.innerText);
          visibleParagraphs = visibleParagraphs + paragraph.innerText
        }
      }

      // console.log( visibleParagraphs);//
      return visibleParagraphs
    }
```

Comment: add a class called .item to all your required field : 
`const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item'));`

Comment: @shafavp I have created this code keeping in mind that I will be running this code on browser console as I won't have access to the pages. Hence, I won't be able to change anything on the pages which means I won't be able to add ```.item``` to the classes. But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>The Document Object</h1>
<h2>The querySelectorAll() Method</h2>

<p>Add a background color all elements with class="example":</p>
<h2 class="example">A heading</h2>
<p class="example">A paragraph.</p> 
<div>Hello div </div>

<script>
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".example , p, div");
for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  nodeList[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

it may be useful for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).